# Is it possible to use a monospaced font for an information focused webpage?

Tags: website-design, fonts

Monospaced fonts are used mainly for code editors and other special purposes and not usually for normal web pages, like an online newspaper for instance. I ponder however with the idea to do this and would like to know:

Can a monospaced font be used successfully to deliver information (not art work)? Or is the idea just 100% wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah why not? Monospace fonts originated from typewriters. Because typewriter letter blocks have a fixed width, it was necessary to make a font on a fixed grid.

Back in the days journalists used typewriters to write their blogs (haha. Anachronism there :)) it would be perfectly fine on a conceptual level.

But on a legibility level its a whole different subject. Monospace fonts are harder to read. They need extra care.

But why not give it a try.